# How to fix framebuffer resolution for external monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, framebuffer

With Xubuntu 18.10, the framebuffer has the proper resolution only for the built-in screen of my laptop (1366×768).  When using an external monitor through HDMI (1280×1024), the Xubuntu logo at shutdown has a wrong aspect ratio (it is too tall) but even worse, I cannot see the bottom lines in the framebuffer, which makes working on the console very difficult.

I tried to change GRUB settings (something along https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?306271-uEFI-grub2-efi-nVidia-high-res-efifb-(non-nouveau)-virtual-consoles) but it had zero effect.

I’m willing to accept that I have to change the configuration every time I switch between internal and external screen, but how does one change the resolution of the framebuffer in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried to set the resolution with xrandr? Try `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1280x1024`

Comment: xrandr has no effect, AFAICS. But does it control the framebuffer consoles at all?

Comment: There are 2 entries in the man page of xrandr `--fb` and `--fbmm`

Comment: Both entries do not refer to the framebuffers (those that you get with Alt+Ctrl+F1).

Comment: I totally misread that, sorry. Are you familiar with this command? https://linux.die.net/man/8/fbset

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it yields `ioctl FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument` for whatever geometry I pass.  I now look into modeset …

Comment: This seems to affect a wide range of distributions. Googling the error message I came across some posts where they suggest passing all zero values for timing parameters due to a bug.